# Could not find a part of the path Exception Thrown

Tags: .net, powershell

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

try
{
    $fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("somedirectory", "*",[IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories); 
}
catch [Exception]
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}
foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
{ 
    [Console]::WriteLine($fileName); 
}
```

**The above code throws the exception**

Could not find a part of the path '\blah\dah\dodah\updity_and_suppy\03. Docs hokeypokey\imp\lalalid\welpy
 qwerty-poloky Architecture - tada sausy (from Internet) todady poloky TPG upodsl poliduity\B4PE to Y3 - E
xternal asdfds polm toluky to Saftgy 3 yuppy App\Old Docs'.

I've obfuscated the path a little but the layout is there.

The reason I am trying to use GetFiles instead of Get-ChildItem is due to speed. I am traversing over potentially 100s of terabytes over a network and Get-ChildItem is too slow when retrieving a .Net object and contains more information than I need.

The question I am asking is "Can this error be ignored using something similar to > -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ?" or "Is there a way to stop this error from occurring?"

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: please provide full exception. Is the provided filepath absolute or is it actually longer? It's pretty close to windows's maxpath limit (length)

Comment: @Graimer That is the full exception that I received minus the path which is obfuscated(masked) for security reasons. It is shorter after the process. I realize that anything over 260 chars is over the Max_Path. I'm wondering if there is a way to handle this error and continue(Get-ChildItem does this but is too slow) or is there another language is more suited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

function recurse
{

    param($path)

    try
    {
           $fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path)
           [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$directInf = New-Object IO.DirectoryInfo($path)
           $folders = $directInf.GetDirectories()
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
           $_.Exception.Message
           $folders = @()
     }

    foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
    {

          #[Console]::WriteLine($fileName); 

    }

    Remove-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name fileEntries 

    foreach($folder in $folders)
    {
        recurse($path + $folder + "\")
    }
    Remove-Variable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name folders 
}

recurse #path that you wish to search
```

This is probably not the best solution but it will recursively go through the folders and get the filename, is much faster than get-childitem over the network and handles the exception thrown by paths over 260 and continues(it doesn't resolve the problem, just ignores and continues). The Remove-Variable is to help with memory issues, whether it helps or not is another matter.